# react-native fbsdk: can't find import symbol

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I followed these steps: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk for the android.

react-native: v0.52.0

But I get the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
```

Do I have to add anything to the gradle build files? It doesn't say anything in the documentation.

Comment: Did you run also the steps to integrate the Facebook SDK into your Android code? Linking the RN library is half the installation

Comment: Yes, but it says I can skip the first steps about the gradle stuff